# Laravel: npm run hot keep running old project instead of current

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack

So weird, I have previous project on my xampp\htdocs laravel+vue I been using HMR on that project. Now I created new project laravel + react I'm trying to guess why HMR is not working I tried every piece on github to make work so unlucky I also try to recreate node_modules and package.json and clear npm not working either.

Then I found this issue when I run npm run hot on my current project `kintool> npm run hot` there is no `[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.` on console. But when I open my old project it has. My target location is on current project but it runs on my old project instead of current project thats why my current project is not working whatever I try.

I tried removing my old project on the htdocs, still the same looks like its targeting my old project whenever I run npm run hot

My webpack.mix.js on current app

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.react('resources/assets/js/bundle.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.disableSuccessNotifications();
```

Old project webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
     .stylus('resources/assets/stylus/app.styl', 'public/css/vuetify.css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/global.sass', 'public/css/global.css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/media-hover-effect.sass', 'public/css/media-hover-effect.css')
   .copyDirectory('node_modules/font-awesome','public/copiedDir/font-awesome')
   .js('resources/assets/js/jscripts/myscripts.js', 'public/js');
mix.disableSuccessNotifications();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what's the reason. I'm using laravel-mix 2.1

There are 2 ways to solve this

1.) Downgrade to 1.7 or 1.6

2.) or follow this [step](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1437) which what I did. You need to configure webpack-dev-server.

> I found a potential fix for this, it looks like removing the leading
>   slash on entrypoints in the generated Webpack config fixes issues with
>   HMR.
>
> I would submit a PR with this but when I made these changes a bunch of
>   tests started failing and I don't have enough time at the moment to
>   look into the reasons why
>
> You can apply these changes in your node_modules/laravel-mix
>   directory:
>
> In src/builder/Entry.js: on line 90: Change:
>
> let name = output.pathFromPublic(Config.publicPath).replace(/.js$/,
>   '').replace(/\/g, '/'); To:
>
> let name = output.pathFromPublic(Config.publicPath).replace(/.js$/,
>   '').replace(/\/g, '/').replace(/^//, ''); This fixes issues with JS.
>
> In src/builder/webpack-rules.js on line 137: Change:
>
> let outputPath =
>   preprocessor.output.filePath.replace(Config.publicPath + path.sep,
>   path.sep).replace(/\/g,'/'); To:
>
> let outputPath =
>   preprocessor.output.filePath.replace(Config.publicPath + path.sep,
>   path.sep).replace(/\/g,'/').replace(/^//, '');